# PMC magnetic wall aproximation of a resonator logic

Tags: waveguide

As we can see below, they say that for $TE_{01\delta}$ if a wave hits the border between dielectric constants then it will reflect back so why exactly is this property is PMC (as they say below)
PMC is perfect electric conductor, what does it have to do with reflecting a wave?
I see PMC only as a boundary that allows magnetic field to pass threw it while electric field vanishes.
TE is transverse electric so we have magnetic component with the direction of propagation.
I can't see why PMC has the property to reflect $TE_{01}$ wave?
Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: I do not understand your question, please, give more detail; you are referring to a perfect electric conductor but wrote PMC, etc. You should explicitly spell out what is shown on the picture (reference?), input/output modes, your notation, what is $TE_{01\delta}$, etc.  otherwise nobody will know what you are talking about. Also, this forum uses mathjax to write equations, just click on the "edit" under any post and see how others may use it.

Comment: It appears to me that this is a circular waveguide with a magnetic (not electric) wall but I do not know what $01\delta$ means. The text below the figure correctly reminds you that if you have a dielectric interface between $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ and you fix  $\epsilon_1$ but let $\epsilon_2 \to \infty$ (in practice, $\epsilon_2/\epsilon_1 >> 1$) then the interface will act as magnetic wall, i.e., an "open" circuit, hence $\Gamma = 1$.

Comment: Hello hyportnex,for TE01 mode we have Hz component it hits PMC wall what gamma=1 and not -1? Thanks.